# Start Quasar/Vue app inside a plugin Promise

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-2, quasar-framework

For an app I need to load dynamic configurations (read from external service) before I can bootstrap my Quasar app.

In other Vue apps I use a `require.ensure` or a `Promise` in `main.js` and load the app after everything else is ready, but since Quasar added the concept of [App Plugins](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-plugins.html) this won't work anymore as there is no Promises or Chaining available, resulting in race conditions as the App needs configurations that are not available yet.

I looked at their internals and they seem to load plugins in a `forEach` block from an auto-generated file, not ready for this scenario.

Here's an excerp from the usual solution in `main.js` (using `require.ensure` as the file auto-generated on the same server by another service)

```
require.ensure(['./config.js'], (require) => {
  const config = require('.config.js');

  // ... use values in config to bootstrap axios, apollo and such

  // And finally start the Vue app
  new Vue({ ... })
})
```

Any ideas on how to do this in a Quasar or Webpack way ?

The only alternative I can think of now is to fork&patch Quasar, but maybe I'm missing something and there is another way.